# Cordova App sqlite database viewer on runtime app testing like Web SQL

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I am creating Hybrid app for android & iOS platform using Cordova. In this app I need to store information in database (currently storing in WebSQL). But WebSQL not supporting in android 4.4.4 version. Now we decided to switch from WebSQL to Sqlite. in WebSQL I can view database by inspecting app using Google Chrome browser. But After implementing [sqlite plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-sqlite-2)
Im not able to view database while app is running (or inspect mode in google chrome).

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

if you are executing on a device and need to view the data stored by sqlite, install the "[stetho](https://github.com/OutSystems/cordova-plugin-stetho-android)" plugin, it lets you open a dev tool with sqlite data. connect the device on the computer, open the app, open the chrome and type in the navigation bar "chrome://inspect", and click the link related to "stetho".